# How to delete all over top 10 rows from a table using Sql

Tags: php

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM
 l2 WHERE
 data NOT IN ( 
     SELECT Top 10  data
     FROM l2
     ORDER BY data desc
)", $con);
```

Comment: Also `Top 10` is `sql-server` syntax, `mysql_query` won't work with `sql-server`. What do you have? Error reporting also would help and the default note here that `mysql_` is deprecated/removed.

Comment: $chat = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM l2 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 4", $con);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM l2 WHERE data NOT IN (
    '$chat')", $con);
I tried in this way, but then delete everything

Comment: `$chat` is a resource, not your IDs. You need to fetch the results, or use that as a subquery.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: The approved answer didnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
database name = deletelimit10
table name = content
column name = name

table content is:

id  name
1    name1
2    name2
3    name3
etc more than 10
```

After run complet PDO, we have only 10 rows.

Complet PDO:

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=deletelimit10', "root", "");

$query = $dbh->query("DELETE FROM content
WHERE
  name NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT name
      FROM content
      ORDER BY name DESC
      LIMIT 10) k
  )"); // Run your query

?>
```

This "k" is: every derived table (AKA sub-query) must indeed have an alias. I.e. each query in brackets must be given an alias (AS whatever), which can the be used to refer to it in the rest of the outer query.
My table name is "name" and column in table has name "name".

Comment: Could you give an example where table have real name and column in table have real name, because it is confusing when everything is "NAME"

Comment: I try like that and It works. Thank you very much

mysql_query("DELETE FROM l2 WHERE data NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT data from l2 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 10)k)", $con);

Comment: hi maybe you can converted this into PDO?

Comment: Ok. I must find that example.

Comment: im try but is not running $sql =$db->query("DELETE FROM l2 WHERE data NOT IN(SELECT * FROM (SELECT data from l2 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 10)k)");

Answer (score 0):

Remember, the **mysql_** is deprecated, but you can use **limit**:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM l2 WHERE
data IN ( 
   SELECT Top 10  data
   FROM l2
   ORDER BY data desc
   LIMIT 10
)", $con);
```

Comment: Ops, don't use the NOT IN, only IN

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you really should use a more modern extension for connecting to a MySQL database. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) is a good choice:

```
<?php
$dbConn = new \PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db;charset=utf8',
    'user',
    'password',
    [\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
);

$sql = <<<SQL
DELETE FROM l2 WHERE data NOT IN (
    SELECT data FROM (SELECT data FROM l2 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 10) d
)
SQL;

$dbConn->exec($sql);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery''

Comment: "<<<SQL" or  it is written exactly?

Comment: im try but is not running
 $sql =$db->query("DELETE FROM l2 WHERE data NOT IN(SELECT * FROM (SELECT data from l2 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 10)k)");

Comment: The `<<<SQL` is there heredoc terminator. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: @martynas When you say it's "not running", what error do you see?